# Repairing 2 long cuts in vinyl flooring

Tags: repair, flooring, vinyl

I need to repair 2 long cuts in the vinyl flooring in my kitchen. The 2 cuts are near each other and probably take up about 8 inches in length. Everything I've read has talked about patching but I'm not sure I could (or should) cut a square of this length for repair. We don't have any original flooring left from the previous owners. We plan on changing out the flooring but that won't be for at least 2 years. Would repairing the cuts as if they were small cuts work or do I need to cut a big patch to fix? [image: Cuts in vinyl flooring]

Answer (score 1):

1. Pry up some of the cut so you can apply a fresh adhesive
2. Apply some vinyl flooring adhesive (preferably in caulk tube form since you don't need much) to the floor
3. Press the flooring down and wipe up any excess adhesive
4. After letting the adhesive cure, apply seam sealer to the edges to make the floor seamless